# my ads are not showing up

Tags: android, admob, ads

i am just trying to learn how to add ads in android app.but the ads are not showing up.i don't know why its not coming up

here is my mainactivity.xml

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello World!" />


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
android:layout_marginTop="443dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView"       
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.a1407268.admob;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why this is `android:layout_marginTop="443dp"` ? `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` will be worked

Comment: `mainactivity.xml` or `activity_main.xml` ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan ya that is activity_main.xml....my mistake..sry

Comment: @arunodaysingh Make sure you've `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: @Piyush its just the alignment .i have changed it to android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" but the ads doesn't come up...other other idea????

Comment: @AbhishekAryan done that...still i doesnt comes up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're testing your app then use `addTestDevice()` to check Ad alignment.

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);

AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

Otherwise If your App is live then and not able to show any Ad then you've to wait for some time.

According to Google

> "It could be that you have only recently created a new Ad Unit ID and
>   requesting for live ads. It could take a few hours for ads to start
>   getting served if that is that case. If you are receiving test ads
>   then your implementation is fine. Just wait a few hours and see if you
>   are able to receive live ads then. If not, can send us your Ad Unit ID
>   for us to look into."

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/fBe3YL3ffpo

Comment: thanks a lot for your help....actually i didn't put the device id.after writing this i am getting the test id and waiting to see the ads after reading your comment.thanks a lot for your help.